# ansible with_items single or multiple module call

Tags: ansible

When I setup an ansible task with `with_items` to install software with the `apt` module like this:

```
- name: ensure base packagase are installed
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  with_items: "{{ system_base_packages }}"
```

Will the `apt` module be called multiple times as well as the `update_cache`? Or is this a single call to the module?

My main concern is that I do not want to update the cache multiple times for every software inside the array to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following modules `apk, apt, dnf, package*, pacman, pkgng, yum, zypper` are smart to squash your items into single run.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787609/ansible-shell-and-with-items/39789117#39789117) SO answer for links.

- `package` as of Ansible 2.3 (2017-04-12) [no longer has it's items squashed](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/24581). This can be overcome by specifying `squash_actions=` in the `[defaults]` section of your [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_configuration.html#squash-actions) file.

Comment: Is that even the case when I have different `state` such as latest or a specific version or even mixed updates within this task?

Comment: Never tried that with different states.

Comment: If you have concerns about cache updates, you can run `update_cache` as separate task and don't update it during module checking, or pass `cache_valid_time` parameter.

Comment: But if I run `cache_update` as a separate task (in real mode) it will always return `[changed]`, even if no updates would be available. The only workaround came with ansible 2.2.1 and having it in the same task as with the installs/updates itself